# how to pattern a cut-loft around a helix

Tags: solidworks

I'm trying something fancier..  hopefully it will be clear from the screen-shot.. linear and circular patterns work.  now, however, I'd like to spiral the cuts.  first try isn't working..  it gave me an error at one point, but I didn't comprehend it, and it hasn't shown up again.[image]

here is a second screen-capture presenting the problem.  I try to select the outside of the cylinder as the surface that the pattern should be normal to, and it doesn't work..[image]

partial solution:  I tried the following (somewhat lame, it gave me no sound?) tutorial and this time it worked:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9xSMBdqcr4 .  two things I've learned:  the first one.. is rather trivial but irks me for some reason.  a helix can't be created from an existing sketch,  you have to create a fresh sketch just for it.  this seems.. wasteful of time and effort, particularly considering the second thing I've learned:  in order for the curve driven pattern to work, the helical path -must- be on the surface to which the object to be patterned is to be  normal...  so the question would become, why is solidworks built this way.  is  there a reason for it, or is  it just an oversight? :-)

Comment: Tried doing the lofts as unmerged solids rather than cuts, patterning the bodies, and doing a combine/subtract at the end?

Comment: You could always make this effect from a series of linear and circular, too.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift series of linear and circular?  ... you really think that's possible?

Comment: "Tried doing the lofts as unmerged solids rather than cuts, patterning the bodies, and doing a combine/subtract at the end?" -nope. I haven't.  thanks for the thought!

Comment: I only suggested it since you said that linear worked for you. You could do linear with a spacing equal to the pitch of the helix, Then circular, and then use the move/copy bodies command to raise the bodies up to the level of the helix (lift by fractional height of the helix pitch relative to the number of degrees rotated) - this is a very messy way, but it *would* work, and without having the file it's always hard to diagnose why your curve driven pattern (which is certainly a better method) isn't working.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift  -sounds pretty fancy.  and looks it to, from your answer! ;-)  that said, providing you with an example file shouldn't be a problem :-)  I'll get back to you with that! :-D

Comment: You were using 2018 iirc - I have 2015 at home and 2019 at work, so I won’t be able to send a working file back unfortunately

Comment: oh.. :-S sigh.  well, thankfully, however, It now works!  I followed this tutorial, to the extent  that it qualifies as a tutorial (no sound for me..) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9xSMBdqcr4  and it's working!  now I just have to track back from there to see what was wrong the first time..  I'll let you know what I find out!

Comment: ok, I've learned two things.  the first one.. is rather trivial but irks me for some reason.  a helix can't be created from an existing sketch,  you have to create a fresh sketch just for it.  this seems.. wasteful of time and effort, particularly considering the second thing I've learned:  in order for the curve driven pattern to work, the helical path -must- be on the surface to which the object to be patterned is to be  normal...

Comment: Not true - you just need a sketch that contains only a circle.

Comment: have it your way ;-P seems you still know something I don't know.  I have a way that works for me, I'll just be grateful for that.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've pretty much answered this in the comments, but didn't want to hyperlink an image:

- Make your loft into an un-merged solid, that can be used as a cut tool later.
- Pattern bodies instead of features, this is *always* more reliable

Another thing to note - you can use the helix feature directly as your path, there's no need for a 3D sketch.

[image: helix loft pattern]