# Pattern a tangential feature around a helix

Tags: solidworks

I'm modelling a piece to 3D print which will be used for a small test, and in an effort to save time in manually filleting every edge, I wanted to make a cut on the top one then pattern it down to the bottom. This has proved a waste of time, but I would like to know how to do this for future reference!

[image]

I can pattern it without maintaining tangency without any issues, this has worked both when attempting to pattern both a swept cut and a body (which would be removed later). However when I try to make the patterned parts tangent to the helix, it doesn't work.

[image]

First it asks me to specify a face on which the curve lies ("face normal"), but then it won't let me select any faces or planes.

[image]

If I try to select Plane1, Plane2 or any of the faces of the part itself, nothing happens. It doesn't give me any errors, it simply does not allow me to select them.

I've tried the suggestions in this post ([how to pattern a cut-loft around a helix](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33074/how-to-pattern-a-cut-loft-around-a-helix)) but without success, nor has the video linked there helped (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkdzB5I-qcY).

Can anyone help?